# PySimpleGUI: Get selected value in OptionMenu

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Using PySimpleGUI in Python, I have a window that has an OptionMenu element, which is basically a TKinter pimped combobox.
I want to retrieve the currently selected element.

Having this OptionMenu:

```
sg.OptionMenu(default_value ='Live',values=('Live', 'Frozen', 'Delayed'),key='-MARKETDATA-')
```

Typically you would use this to get the selected menu item:

```
print(window['-MARKETDATA-'].get())
```

except that the OptionMenu class does not have a .get() method.

I can get the selected menu item by using:

```
event2, values2 = window.Read(timeout=1)
print(values2['-MARKETDATA-'])
```

but that hardly seems elegant.
Is there another more straightforward way that I overlooked?

Comment: `.get()` is to get `boolean`  value so how a list will get `True `or `False`. thats why `values2['-MARKETDATA-']` is a right approach.

Comment: .get() can also return string data from an sg.Input textbox ....

Comment: you can use `sg.Combo` if u want `.get()`

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative. But I like the OptionMenu better because there you can click the entire element area to make the box/menu drop-down. With the ComboBox you have to click exactly on the small rectangle/triangle. So you have to have a better aim ... ;-)
The benefit of a ComboBox is that you can enter free text also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option `enable_events` in `sg.OptionMenu`, and also no method `get` defined.
Here I enable event for it by `trace` and also get selected value by `values[key]`.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def callback(var, index, mode):
    """
    For OptionMenu
    var - tkinter control variable.
    index - index of var, '' if var is not a list.
    mode - 'w' for 'write' here.
    """
    window.write_event_value("Language", window['Language'].TKStringVar.get())

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

data = ["Arabic", "Chinese", "English", "German", "Japanese", "Latin", "Spanish"]

layout = [
    [sg.OptionMenu(data, default_value=data[2], key='Language')],
    [sg.Button("Click")],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window['Language'].TKStringVar.trace("w", callback)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'Language':
        print(event, values['Language'])
    elif event == 'Click':
        print(event, values['Language'])

window.close()
```